Eye rigging via mapping node
I'm trying to rig these eyes so the bone can move them, rotate them, and scale them.

I can get the location to work fine, but I can't figure out how to get the rotation and scale to work correctly. I want the origin of the scale and rotation to be at the center of the pupil. I've been using the mapping node along with drivers, but can't figure out the right set up.
Here's the blend file:

